# callback function is not being called on event fire

Tags: reactjs, flux

I am learning Flux in ReactJS. I have written a simple code in ReactJS using Flux pattern. In this code some records are being displayed and there is an option to add a new record. The problem is that when I fire an event i.e. when I click the add button, the callback function is not being called from `this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);` and as a result of that, the new record is not being displayed on screen. Therefore please tell, why this `callback` function is not being called? And how to resolve this issue?

**Store.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Dispatcher from './Dispatcher.js';
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

class Store extends EventEmitter {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.records = [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'First Record'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Second Record'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Third Record'
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'Fourth Record'
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                name: 'Fifth Record'
            }
        ]
    };

    createRecord(name, id) {
        this.records.push({
            id: id,
            name: name
        });
        this.emit("change");
    }

    addChangeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback) {
        this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    }

    handleActions(action) {
        switch(action.type) {
            case "ADD_RECORD": {
                this.createRecord(action.name, action.id);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    getRecords() {
        return this.records;
    }
};

const recordsStore = new Store();
Dispatcher.register(recordsStore.handleActions.bind(recordsStore));

export default Store;
```

**View.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Store from './Store.js';
import {addRecord} from "./Action.js";


class View extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.Store = new Store();
        this.state = {records: this.Store.getRecords()};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container" style={{marginTop:'25px'}}>
                <ul className="list-group">
                    <li style={{backgroundColor:'#696969', color:'#f5f5f5', textAlign:'center', padding:'5px', fontSize:'16px', borderRadius:'5px 5px 0px 0px'}}><b>Records</b></li>
                    {this.state.records.map((eachRecord,index) =>
                        <ListItem key={index} singleRecord={eachRecord} />
                    )}
                </ul>
                <input type="text" ref="input"/>
                <button  onClick={()=>addRecord(this.refs.input.value)}>Add</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.Store.addChangeListener("change", this.updateStore);
    }

    updateStore() {
        this.setState({
            records: this.Store.getRecords()
        });
    }
}

class ListItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li className="list-group-item" style={{cursor:'pointer'}}>
                <b>{this.props.singleRecord.name}</b>
                <button style={{float:'right'}}>Delete</button>
            </li>
        );
    }
}

export default View;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would set up a flux store -- the key points are:

- register the dispatch callback in the constructor
- It makes it easier to have a single `CHANGE_EVENT` constant and hide it inside the store.
- Typically you'll want your stores to only have one instance. So when you export it you would `export default new Store()`. That way all components will be able to use the same store.

**Store**

```
const CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';

class Store extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
    Dispatcher.register(this.handleActions.bind(this));
  }

  createRecord(name, id) {
    // code..
    this.emitChange();
  }

  emitChange() {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  }

  addChangeListener(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }

  removeChangeListener(callback) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }

  handleActions(action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'ADD_RECORD': {
        this.createRecord(action.name, action.id);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  getRecords() {
    return this.records;
  }
}

export default new Store();
```

--

In the view, you should bind your listeners in `componentDidMount` and remember to remove the listeners in `componentWillUnmount`.

**View**

```
import Store from './Store';

class View extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {records: Store.getRecords()};
  }

  render() {
    // code..
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Store.addChangeListener(this.updateStore);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Store.removeChangeListener(this.updateStore);
  }

  // use this syntax to keep context or use .bind in the constructor
  updateStore = () => {
    this.setState({
      records: Store.getRecords()
    });
  }
}
```